# Got error when use RadioGroup

Tags: android-radiogroup

I don't know how to fix the error in the images below:

[image: Example 1]

[image: Example 2]

Comment: Please post your code as text in your question, not as a screenshot.

Comment: @JAL I know but if I post my code as text, you will not be able to see a red underline. Btw, the problem has been resolved, thanks for your comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you didn't imported 'OnCheckedChangeListener' in your class. Just keep
`import android.widget.RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener;`  in your imports.

Comment: Oh, I thought that the system will automatically import. It's work, thank you.